# In ChatGPT, what is the difference between Reinforcement-Learning-from-Human-Feedback and Data-Re-Label?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, gpt

[Reinforcement-Learning-from-Human-Feedback](https://openai.com/blog/instruction-following/) vs [TrainingData-Label-Again](https://guotong1988.github.io/research/2021/12/01/relabel-is-all-you-need/).

Comment: Can you add a link to any material about Data Re-Labeling from Reward? RLHF is a known technique, but the other one does not ring a bell for me, and googling/google scholar did not render any relevant result

Comment: Also, in a generative model like ChatGPT, there are no labels in the sense of a classification problem. It generates sequences of tokens. RLHF is used to lean the model toward generating desirable sequences.

Comment: I have edited the question: Reward come from human labeling.

Comment: Language models don't use labels. What labels do humans produce? How are the labels used to compute rewards?

Comment: Please, consider marking the answer as correct or, alternatively, commenting on why you this it is not, or what is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

ChatGPT, being a generative model, generates sequences of tokens. There are no labels in the sense of a classification problem. Therefore, re-labeling using the reward signal does not make sense in the context of ChatGPT.

On the other hand, [RLHF](https://huggingface.co/blog/rlhf) is used to lean the model toward generating desirable sequences.